# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: MockMaker

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, mockito, android-library

Trying to run instrumentation test on AS.

stuck with this Error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker
> at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader$1.invoke(PluginLoader.java:66)
> at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
> at $Proxy4.isTypeMockable(Unknown Source)

ExampleInstrumentedTest.java

```
      @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
        public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
        
            @Mock
            Context context;
     
  @Before
    public void init(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

        @Test
            public void testDisabledFlag()  {
                ChanceValidator chanceValidator  = new ChanceValidator(context);
                Validator.ValidationResult result = chanceValidator.validate(2);
                assertEquals(result, Validator.ValidationResult.NO_ERROR);
        }
       }
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

     android{
        ..
        defaultConfig {
                testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        
         testOptions {
                unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
            }
    }
    
    
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        // Unit testing dependencies
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        // Set this dependency if you want to use the Hamcrest matcher library
        testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
        // more stuff, e.g., Mockito
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
        compile project(':mortar')
        compile project(':mockito-core-2.6.6')
    }
```

**Update:**
After commenting line-

MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

It is building fine(No Exception) but context mocked is now null.

Comment: post full `ExampleInstrumentedTest`

Comment: @Intellij it is a full test

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This Worked in my case:

```
dependencies { 
def mockito_version = '2.7.1' // For local unit tests on your development machine
 testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:$mockito_version" // For instrumentation tests on Android devices and emulators
 androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-android:$mockito_version"
 }
```

I didn’t comment initMocks

Comment: Still getting **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker**

Comment: What is important here is that `testCompile` needs the `mockito-core` artifact and `androidTestCompile` needs the `mockito-android` artifact. My problem was that I used `mockito-android` for both which led to the error.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I was working on a project that does not use the maven build system. So this is what worked for me.

Navigated to the maven repo for mockito (used v2.26): https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.26.0. I downloaded the jar.
On the same page at the bottom, I looked up the dependencies. For mockito 2.26.0, these dependencies are:

- Byte Buddy v.1.9.10
  (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.9.10)
- Byte Buddy Java Agent v1.9.10
  (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy-agent/1.9.10)
- Objenesis v2.6
  (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.objenesis/objenesis/2.6) I
  downloaded the jar files for the above mockito dependencies.

In Eclipse I created a user library containing the four jar file and added it to my project.

*NB: (creating the library is optional, you can add the jars directly to your project build path)*

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This doesn't work. Mockito in its MANIFEST.MF file has a list of Buddy-/Objenesis-dependencies with explicit versions to use.

Comment: I've tried to use and replace with last versions (1.10.8 \ 3.0.1) of these libs, but at tests launching Studio forcibly loads (1.10.5 \ 2.6 )

Answer (score 4):

Do not explicitly include mockito, let powermock pull in what it needs.

Comment: I also have the same problem.  I added the dependencies for the mockito-core but not for mockito-android, because I am not running the tests in Android device. I run tests on Linux environment only.

`testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.47"`

Comment: Nice shot!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem resolved after adding transitive dependencies for 'mockito-core'.
I was facing this problem in eclipse. I was using 'mockito-core 3.8.0' along with 'mockito-junit-jupiter  3.8.0'.
At first I tried to resolve this by changing JRE to JDK  in Project/ Java Build Path ((as many have posted this as resolution), but that did not solve the problem.
Then I added below 3 transitive dependencies for 'mockito-core 3.8.0' explicitly, and it worked!

```
1. net.bytebuddy » byte-buddy  v1.10.20
2. net.bytebuddy » byte-buddy-agent  v1.10.20
3. org.objenesis » objenesis  v3.1
```

(https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.8.0  - see compiled dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Quarkus on a big project with many people.

Most of our microservices used this dependency version

```
<net.bytebuddy.version>1.12.9</net.bytebuddy.version>
```

One microservice used:

```
<net.bytebuddy.version>1.11.0</net.bytebuddy.version>
```

Which was not compatible with our

```
<artifactId>quarkus-junit5-mockito</artifactId>
```

When I added more tests on a resource, I got the error of this question.

I changed the bytebuddy to 1.12.9 and mockito worked.

Make sure your bytebyddy's version is compatible with you mockito version.

Updated either one of them to be compatible with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try using latest version of junit. With junit version 4.2 & no byte-buddy jar I was getting this issue. Using junit 4.13.2 helped me fix this issue.