# Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker

Tags: mockito

I'm getting following exception once tests is started:

```
    Testcase: treeCtorArgumentTest(com.xythos.client.drive.cachedtree.CachedTreeTest):  Caused an ERROR
Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader$1.invoke(PluginLoader.java:66)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.isTypeMockable(Unknown Source)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.typeMockabilityOf(MockUtil.java:29)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockCreationValidator.validateType(MockCreationValidator.java:22)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.validatedSettings(MockSettingsImpl.java:168)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.confirm(MockSettingsImpl.java:162)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:64)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1687)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1600)
    at com.xythos.client.drive.cachedtree.CachedTreeTest.setUp(CachedTreeTest.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/bytebuddy/dynamic/loading/ClassLoadingStrategy
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.<init>(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:33)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyMockMaker.<init>(ByteBuddyMockMaker.java:22)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:54)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginRegistry.<init>(PluginRegistry.java:18)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.<clinit>(Plugins.java:17)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.<clinit>(MockUtil.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

This is my test:

```
package com.xythos.client.drive.cachedtree;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)

    public class CachedTreeTest {

        public CachedTreeTest() {
        }

        @Test
        public void treeCtorArgumentTest() {
        somemock m = mock(SomeClass.class);
        }
    }
```

I'm using NetBeans 8.2. I've downloaded mockito-core-2.7.0.jar, and then I select "Test Libraries"->"Add Jar" and added mockito-core-2.7.0.jar.

Classpath and everything looks ok, I',m still getting exception.

Any advice?

Comment: Check solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41964561/4903889

Comment: Upgrading to a newer version of Mockito helped me solve this problem.

Comment: Clearing Gradle cache and downloading all dependencies from scratch fixed it for me. (See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13567793/4568679 for clearing cache)

Comment: I had a typo in the file `src/test/resources/org/powermock/extensions/configuration.properties` causing the exception shown.

Comment: I invalidated cache of IDE and restarted, it solved the problem for me

Comment: My problem was that I had some private static final variables at the test class, when I removed these variables it worked again.

Comment: Had this problem, mvn test worked fine on the commandline but Eclipse kept throwing this. Double checked m2 repo, tried to delete the mockito-inline folder/jar yet it was locked by Eclipse. That was a clue, to fix it all I did was close and reopen Eclipse - it's a different engine so ...

Answer (score 118):

If you are using powermock ensure that your dependencies point to:

```
org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2
```

instead of

```
org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito
```

Comment: I don't know the exact cause yet, but this answer helped me when my tests failed after upgrading Spring version 1.5.14-RELEASE to 2.0.4-RELEASE

Comment: The question has nothing to do with powermock. The problem occurs when you use jre instead of jdk.

Comment: I am not using **PowerMock**

Comment: And if you aren't using PowerMock? The question did reference interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker.

Comment: Why unrelated answers get so many upvotes?

Answer (score 65):

Missing reference to:

- byte-buddy-1.6.5.jar
- byte-buddy-agent-1.6.5.jar
- objenesis-2.5.jar

Since Mockito 2.0.2 beta, Mockito-core has dependencies.

Comment: those libraries are included by default, this is not the solution

Comment: I can confirm that adding the latest byte-budy (and more likely, the byte-buddy-agent) JARs to a "latest greatest" mockito setup help here. For me, the exception from the question showed up after enabling "mocking of final" classes with mockito 2.

Comment: these are transitive dependencies you do not have to add them explicitly.

Comment: For **`mockito 2.25.1`** you only need `objenesis-3.0.1.jar` and `byte-buddy-1.9.12.jar`.

Comment: thease deps are listed in the [maven page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.26.0) too, at the bottom of the page. Including it resolve the problem.

Comment: These are only included by default (as suggested by @Eduardo) if you are not using a build system (maven/gradle) to automatically resolve the dependencies, otherwise this could be the solution.

Comment: The project currently I'm working on manually imports `jar` files, and this answer worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, had to explicitly add these 3 for it to work

Answer (score 21):

I had Byte Buddy on classpath (is transitive dep of Mockito 2.8.9) and still got the exception. Reason for me was that I ran the Unit tests with JRE instead of JDK. Switching to JDK worked for me.

Comment: How did you change this?

Comment: @TaranmeetSingh if you're running with Android Studio, go to File > Project Structure > SDK location, and check the paths to your JDK are correct. (You'll need to download a JDK if you haven't already from the Oracle website.)

Comment: Hi @LydiaRalph thanks for the suggestion actually I had a altogether different problem. I was writing Unit test cases for one of the modules(which are also standalone android studio projects) but I had instead opened the whole project in  android studio. Switching to the stand alone project solved this for me.

Comment: @Stefano , how to switch as I've not mentioned any where using jdk or jre

Comment: This fixed it for me. I just removed the JRE from Eclipse's Java Runtimes, leaving only the JDK.

Comment: I keep forgetting doing this, Thanks a bunch. I should remove my JREs too

Answer (score 18):

This problem with Mockito2 occurs if you enable the option to mock final classes.

> This means when in your **test/resources/mockito-extensions** directory
>   you have the file called **org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker** with the
>   following content **mock-maker-inline**.

In that case byte-buddy, which is a transitive dependency for mockito-core, has the problem to attach own agent to the java process. But the problem occurs only when you use JRE.

The solution would be either:

- Use JDK instead of JRE

or

- add `-javaagent:byte-buddy-agent-*.jar` as a VM option

Comment: In Android Studio how do you check if you are using JRE instead of JDK, and how would you change it?

Comment: I have the same problem with Android Studio. Was anybody successful?

Comment: Still seeing this issue what to do?

Answer (score 17):

Well, after a lot of research , solution for me is super simple :

update Mockito lib version to latest

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.10.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:3.10.0'
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, problems immediately resolved after upgrading from 2.7.2 to 4.2.0. Note that you still need to set up the `mock-maker-inline` extension.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem - same stacktrace appear in my log. It is typically problem with project setup... OR
**The problem can be in the bytebuddys JARs if these were not downloaded correctly.**
 When I try to check class ClassLoadingStrategy manually then I get *zip* error.

**In that case it is just enough manually delete the Byte Buddy from local maven directory, usually located at:

*{home}/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/***


The next try to run project or test they will be downloaded again and should work as expected.

Unfortunatelly common Java ClassLoader faces in the same way when class or jar missing as well as the jar is corrupted.

Comment: There is another possibility: Hibernate also have `net.bytebuddy*` as a dependency, so may the dependencies being in conflict with each other.

Answer (score 6):

#### Problem: PowerMock + Mockito + TestNG + PowerMockTestCase

*Sharing my problem/solution in case it helps anybody.*

My dependencies were all pointed correctly:

```java
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.47'
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-core:1.7.4'
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-testng:1.7.4'
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.4'
```

But I still got the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker

    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader$1.invoke(PluginLoader.java:66)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.isTypeMockable(Unknown Source)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.typeMockabilityOf(MockUtil.java:29)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockCreationValidator.validateType(MockCreationValidator.java:22)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.validatedSettings(MockSettingsImpl.java:186)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.confirm(MockSettingsImpl.java:180)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:62)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1729)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:33)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:16)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.createMockFor(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:38)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.process(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:62)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processIndependentAnnotations(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:57)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:41)
    at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:69)
```

My test was something as such:

```java
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockTestCase;
import static org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks;

@PrepareForTest(MyClass.class)
public class MyTest extends PowerMockTestCase {

    @BeforeTest
    public void init() {
        initMocks(this);
    }
}
```

As mentioned in this thread, removing the `initMocks()` method removes the error, but all the mocks become null.

---

#### ✅ Solution: BeforeTest VS BeforeMethod

What I found out for my case is that `@BeforeTest` was actually posing a problem.
Changing it to `@BeforeMethod` resolved the error.

```java
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockTestCase;
import static org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks;

@PrepareForTest(MyClass.class)
public class MyTest extends PowerMockTestCase {

    @BeforeMethod // CHANGE THIS!
    public void init() {
        initMocks(this);
    }
}
```

My guess is that it is something to do with beans injection;
`@BeforeTest` is executed before any beans got injected while `@BeforeMethod` is executed after beans injection. Not sure how it really affected though.

Comment: Do you have a solution without powermock?

Comment: @portfoliobuilder if you're not using powermock, I don't think you will encounter the same issue I faced. Probably you could double check the other suggestions given on this thread? Make sure mockito is updated, that you're using jdk and you don't have the missing references.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, after removing `mockito-core`, the test worked!

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>${mockito.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

My version is here, and JDK is 1.8.0_121.

```xml
<properties>
    <powermock.version>2.0.7</powermock.version>
    <mockito.version>2.8.9</mockito.version>
</properties>
```

Now my dependencies are:

- powermock-api-mockito2
- powermock-module-junit4

Comment: Same here. Best to avoid incompatibilities by using what the documentation says: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito-2-Maven

Comment: Removing mockito-core  is a great solution, it also works for Java17. To make it fully working, need add following inside <configuration> of <plugin><groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  </plugin>  
  <argLine>
     --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED 
     ... ...
    </argLine>

Answer (score 4):

For android development you need to import a couple of things:

```
 dependencies {
   testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:+"
   androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-android:+"
 }
```

could not find any reference of this but this is the only one that has worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem when I was using mockitokotlin2. I solved it by using latest version of libraries:

```
testImplementation 'com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:4.4.0'
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove version declaration works for me:

Example:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

remove 2.8.9

After:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

It may due to version issue between jar packages of this dependency.

Comment: you're surely inheriting the version because removing it will break the project. Wrong so wrong answer.

Comment: This was oddly the solution for me. I think this must be because of a parent pom, in my case `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.4.0`. Trying to use a higher version of Mockito led to this strange error, but letting the parent pom's dependency management seemed to alleviate the issue. I had tried to use Mockito `4.8.1` but the dependency management dropped it back to `3.6.0`. Additionally, I read that there is some issue with IntelliJ and the 4.x version's use of byte-buddy.

Comment: I had the same issue using gradle. This is how I solved: `testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core'`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was working on a project that does not use the maven build system. So this is what worked for me.

- Navigated to the maven repo for mockito (used v2.26): https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.26.0. I downloaded the jar.
- On the same page at the bottom, I looked up the dependencies. For mockito **2.26.0**, these dependencies are:

  - Byte Buddy **v.1.9.10** (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.9.10)
  - Byte Buddy Java Agent **v1.9.10** (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy-agent/1.9.10)
  - Objenesis **v2.6** (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.objenesis/objenesis/2.6)
    I downloaded the jar files for the above mockito dependencies
    In Eclipse I created a user library containing the four jar file and added it to my project.

*NB: (creating the library is optional, you can add the jars directly to your project build path)*

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by removing **jmockit** in POM XML for Maven. After that my Junit 5 tests work perfectly.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
        <version>1.41</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

With this dependency I always get an error like:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)
...

Could not initialize inline Byte Buddy mock maker. (This mock maker is not supported on Android.)
...

Caused by: com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: no providers installed
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and tryed @Paskas's solution, worked well Junit Test ok at first.
added the bytebuddy dependency to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
            <artifactId>byte-buddy-dep</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had the same issue and was also able to resolve by explicitly adding the latest ByteBuddy to the POM. Maven isn't resolving the transitive dependency correctly. See here: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/2629

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue and solved it by bumping my version of [org.mockito.mockito-core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core) to the latest release. I had been using an older release for quite some time.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the "byte-buddy-1.7.11.jar" manually from the maven repository path which appears in the error. Maven update the project and the issue will be resolved. Tried and worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Mockito 2 requires dependencies. Adding the two ByteBuddy dependencies below. solved the issue for me:

- byte-buddy-x.x.xx.jar
- byte-buddy-agent-x.x.xx.jar

In my case I include jar files in the project, which can be found at:
https://bintray.com/raphw/maven/ByteBuddy/

If you need it for a Maven project, simply add:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
  <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.14</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that IntelliJ ran the test as integration test. So I needed to create JUnit test manually

[image]

Comment: Maybe you have this unit test in the androidTest directory? I presume AS expect to have instrumented tests in 'androidTest' and unit tests in 'test'.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably having issues with manually adding dependencies to your project. Take note of the mockito-core jar version being used in your project.

Visit this mvn repository link

`https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core/{replace-with-your-mockito-core-version}`

Move to the compile dependencies sections down below in the mvn repository page, download all the appropriate version of the dependencies mockito-core needs.

As of answering this question:

> byte-buddy

> byte-buddy-agent

> objenesis

Add all to the project together with mockito-core and run tests.

Answer (score 1):

I had same error, removing the dependency version for mockito core and doing a fresh mvn clean install fixed the error

Answer (score 1):

This is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55525173/4319941)

Search through the exception stack for the following text:

**"Could not self-attach to current VM using external process"**

If found, add the following JVM option when running your test:

> -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true

With maven for instance:

> mvn test -DargLine="-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true"

Running from IDE (IntelliJ), add JVM option to run configurations:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in my case, some abnormal env setting will also lead to this error:

in ubuntu 16.04, java and javac had been update-alternatives to 7
but $JAVA_HOME had been wrongly set to 8

i remove the $JAVA_HOME, and everything back to normal

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception when switch to **Java 10** and Spring Boot 2.
This dependency combination worked for me:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2-beta</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
        <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
        <artifactId>byte-buddy-agent</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.16</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Adding a bnd aspect to this*

Adding on to [Paskas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41959045/1066531), you also have to include the dependencies in the cnf maven repository, if you're using one (like my `cnf/central.mvn`).

```
org.mockito:mockito-core:2.21.0
net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.8.15
net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:1.8.15
org.objenesis:objenesis:2.6
```

and for convenient referencing, you can include a bnd variable in your `cnf/build.bnd`

```
mockito: org.mockito:mockito-core; version=2.21.0,\
         net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy; version=1.8.15,\
         net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent; version=1.8.15,\
         org.objenesis:objenesis; version=2.6
```

and in your project's bnd file

```
-testpath:\
    ${mockito}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem in one existing project.
I used java 8 and additionally installed java 10.
So I started get this exception.
I deinstalled java 10, it has not helped.
I deleted bytebuddy jars from maven repo, it has not helped.
Only after complete removal of all jars from maven repo I could compile project again.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer to the original poster, since s/he's using Netbeans, but in Eclipse I needed to do "Maven -> Update Project" in order to get tests working again.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me After I removed bytebuddy folder from ${home}.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy and removed byte-buddy-agent,byte-buddy and objenesis dependency from pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, got resolved by adding jcenter in repositories and mockito dependecies.

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
 }
 dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.7.7'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-core:1.7.4'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-testng:1.7.4'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.4'
 }
```

Comment: JCenter is now [end of life](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/) as of May 1, 2021.

Answer (score 0):

```
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.19.0' 
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.19.0"//game changer for your question
```

This second line was a game-changer, android Test implementation and test implementation are not the same test set (android test implementation is a test set for physical devices or emulators)...
you may have dependency for one and writing code, but if you run the different test (local in the android studio without emulator) it will fail (unless..:)

happy testing

Answer (score 0):

In my case, removing:

`{home}/.m2/repository/org/robolectric/`

solved the issue. Next time it runs, it will download those files again.

Answer (score 0):

- **PowerMock** doesn't work with sonar in the first step, the cause of the problem is the combination of powermock and jacoco
- We will not face this issue locally, but if we use sonar for test coverage calculations, the error is as follows

```
Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)
```

- In PowerMock 2.0.9 version, a workaround for this problem is provided they have added an annotation `@PrepareOnlyThisForTest`, this provides the ability for the isolation of a particular Test class.
- Apart from that, we need to add delegate the Runner to SpringRunner using `@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringRunner.class)`

Add Power Mock Dependencies in pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Use the PowerMock Junit Runner for test Class and declare the test class that we’re mocking and delegate SpringRunner

```
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareOnlyThisForTest(ServiceApplication.class)
    @PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringRunner.class)
    public class ExampleControllerTest {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ServiceApplication.class);
        Mockito.when(ServiceApplication.getStatic()).thenReturn("");
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, finally fix it.

It's a long answer, but if you struggling with this issue for a while, hope this can help you.

---

**This is my scenario.**

Android Unit Test

dependency

-> `org.mockito:mockito-core` ()

-> `org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2` (mock static class)

-> `mockito-inline` (enable final class mock)

-> `com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin`

---

### Root Cause -> check the error log

#### Issue1 -> Tools.jar dependency missed

In order to use the mock-maker-inline (mockito-inline), it has dependency
on Tools.jar. We need the dependency.

here is the [link](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/978)

My error log looks like below

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invoking the beforeTestMethod method on PowerMock test listener org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler@49a4bf9a failed.

...

Caused by:
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)

        ... 

        Caused by:
            java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker implementation declared in sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration@3d529098

            ...

            Caused by:
                java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

                ...

               Caused by:
                    org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoInitializationException: 
                    Could not initialize inline Byte Buddy mock maker.
                    ...

                    Caused by:
                                java.lang.NullPointerException
                                    at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:182)
```

So you can see the last line says `attachProvider` throw NullPointerException, this `attachProvider` exists in the tools.jar

class path is `com.sun.tools.attach.AttachProvider`.

So we need to add the dependency for `tools.jar`

---

#### Issue2 -> added wrong dependency for `tools.jar`

I added a wrong dependency for `tools.jar` use the MacOS tools.jar as dependency.

**But our build machine is Linux platform**, So I got this error with diff error log.

```
Cause JDK has different version with different platforms (MacOS, Linux, Windows)
based on the different platforms `VirtualMachine` has diff implementation (MacOS, Linux, Windows)
```

---

Here is the error log

```
Caused by:
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)

        ... 

        Caused by:
            java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker implementation declared in sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration@3d529098

            ...

            Caused by:
                java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

                ...

               Caused by:
                    org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoInitializationException: 
                    Could not initialize inline Byte Buddy mock maker.
                    ...

                    Caused by:
                                java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: sun.tools.attach.BsdVirtualMachine.getTempDir()Ljava/lang/String;
                                    at sun.tools.attach.BsdVirtualMachine.getTempDir(Native Method)
                                    at sun.tools.attach.BsdVirtualMachine.<clinit>(BsdVirtualMachine.java:308)
                                    at sun.tools.attach.BsdAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(BsdAttachProvider.java:63)
                                    at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:208)
```

You can see here, VirtualMachine find the AttachProvider (BsdAttachProvider) but after that it throw an exception.

So which means we added the dependency, but the dependency is wrong.

---

#### How to add the `tools.jar` dependency correctly

(1) add `tools.jar` file to `lib` folder (WRONG)

```
add this `testImplementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['tools.jar'])` in the gradle file

this is not a good approach, cause our build machine (remote) may use the Linux system, but our local machine (Laptop, PC) may use the MacOS or Windows.

this will cause the Issue2  which I mentioned above
```

(2) add `testImplementation files(org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.current().toolsJar)` in gradle file. (WRONG)

```
this one will throw NullPointerException after gradle 4.X.
```

(3) add `testImplementation files("${System.properties['java.home']}/../lib/tools.jar")` in gradle file

```
it will trying to read the environment virable to get the path for the `tools.jar`

Cause both build machine (remote) and local machine (Laptop, PC) need to configure the JDK to make it work.

So this approach should find it's own path even it's based on diff platform (MacOS, Linux, Windows)

This is the approach I am using, If you have better one, please let me know.
```

---

#### Configure Android Studio JDK Location

Don't use the Android Studio Application folder as the JDK location.

Use the `JAVA_HOME` variable path as the JDK location. (you can type `echo JAVA_HOME` in the terminal)

Otherwise when you run the unit test it will show this error

`Transform's input file does not exist: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/lib/tools.jar.`

Cause it's Android Studio Application JDK folder doesn't have the `tools.jar` file. (you can compare the normal configured JDK folder with Android Studio Application Package one)

`/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home`

After these steps, you should be able to run the unit test.

If you got this `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException` when running the unit test

please make sure the mocktio-inline configured correctly.

The issue link (https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/992)

Based on the mockito documents (https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockito#mockito-mock-maker-inline)

It provides two approaches

1. `org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker`
2. `org/powermock/extensions/configuration.properties`

Just try these two approaches, check which one work for you, and just keep one of them.

In my scenario second one works for me.

I also tried this old approach `testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:X.X.X'` it not work for me.

Comment: About the diff between `java.home` and `java_home` here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11345708/4593755)

Answer (score 0):

If you use e.g. a different version of spring-boot-test, you might have a bytebuddy version conflict, as mentioned above. To fix, you can use dependencyManagement:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
     <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
     <version>3.11.2</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
        <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.10</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
        <artifactId>byte-buddy-agent</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.10</version>
     </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks `@Łukasz Rzeszotarski` for his solving - it works for me. I just want to add several details about this problem.

This problem appears when i include `mockito-inline` in my gradle-project, but i don't can refuse of it. It has appear because `mockito-inline` has follows structure:

```
META-INF:
    MANIFEST.MF
mockito-exstensions:
    org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker
    org.mockito.plugins.MemberAccessor
```

where the file `org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` contains:

```
mock-maker-inline
```

This string is needs for mocking final classes and methods and it causes problems, when you using JRE instead of JDK.

Comment: Yo mean, definiing the gradle build tools - java, using jre normally included in Android Studio instead of a jdk version?

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with the same exception, but mine came with some additional info. For me this issue was specifically within android studio and included the following:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ""/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java""
```

it turned out that apparently this library *does not* handle whitespace in the path, and I had to rename my "Android Studio" instance to "AndroidStudio"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case, the cause is because of the wrong version of the byte-buddy.
That was triggered by maven dependency duplication. The duplicate dependency overwrites the higher version of byte-buddy with a lower version making a problem.

**Recap(in my case)**:

1. net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.9.3 should have worked but was overwritten by net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.7.9 from a duplicate dependency which caused my problem.

**solution**:

1. check the maven dependency with the code below:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

2. if you found something like below:

```
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.23.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- (net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.9.3:compile - scope updated from test; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.9.3:test
...
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.7.9:compile
```

you can exclude the duplicate lower version of byte-buddy on pom.xml like below(which is my case):

```
<groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
<artifactId>springfox-core</artifactId>
<version>2.8.0</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
        <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tried aligning the versions of mockito and byte buddy but I still got the error. I did a `mvn dependency:tree` command to look through all the dependencies and I found some proprietary packages from my organisation that included powermock and mockito dependencies. After excluding those dependencies the error disappeared

Answer (score 0):

Find out the mockito core version your project.

Note down the correct dependent version of byte-buddy and include in the project. If the jar is already included with some other version, override the version with this correct version.

Answer (score -1):

Just update to the latest release of `org.mockito:mockito-core`. Once I did, the errors disappeared!