# Testing struts2 application with junit and mockito

Tags: java, mockito, junit4

I am testing an application that uses struts2 framework with junit and mockito. I'm getting an illegalstateexception saying that the plugin Mockmaker cannot be initialized
I have tried adding dependencies like bytebuddy and objenesis but it is still not working
Can someone please guide me on this as I am new to struts2

Exception:

> **`java.lang.IllegalStateException`:** Could not initialize plugin MockMaker

Test code:

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner)
Public class HTest{

    @InjectMocks
    ActionClassToBeTested a

    @Mock //issue with this, I checked by commenting everything
    HttpServletRequest request

    @Mock
    HttpServletResponse response

    @Test
    Public void TestMethod(){
        //Some test logic
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to include the code of a minimal test which produces this error, and the full stack trace of the exception it produces.

Comment: Please include the full stack trace of the exception

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956692/could-not-initialize-plugin-interface-org-mockito-plugins-mockmaker ?

Comment: Already tried it and it's not working, that's why I posted my question separately