# run mockito test code meet an unfortunate trobule

Tags: mockito

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdagN.png)

```
It appears as if your JDK does not supply a working agent attachment mechanism.
Java               : 1.8
JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation
JVM vendor version : 25.251-b08
JVM name           : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 1.8.0_251-b08
JVM info           : mixed mode
OS name            : Mac OS X
OS version         : 10.15.7

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/bytebuddy/agent/ByteBuddyAgent
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.<clinit>(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:117)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 42 more
```

Failed to load interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker implementation declared in sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration@290dbf4

Comment: Post the error logs in image as text

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956692/could-not-initialize-plugin-interface-org-mockito-plugins-mockmaker) help you?